# Facebook Notification Api When Add post to the Website

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sdk

Can we sent a Notification to Fb whenever i added a post in my backend ,means is there any Fb.ui Api for send Notification to all the Fb page Likers.
Just the Push Notification(GCM) in Android

Comment: No, of course not. Publish a post on your Facebook page, then people who are following your page might see it in their newsfeed. That is what you are supposed to do, and only that. Sending notifications to people just because they have liked your page would just be spam.

Comment: phpbaba.com/get-notified How this one is doing something like that

Comment: Well that just uses the [notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications), that is available to canvas apps. But you can not send notifications to just anyone, they need to become users of your app first. And you need to keep the user experience positive – too many users complaining about your notifications or ignoring them will lead to Facebook removing the ability to send them from your app.

Answer (score 1):

Hi all you need to do is use FB API to post your contents to facebook profile/page. FB will take care of sending the notifications to followers/friends based on its internal algorithm. FB basically uses a strong algorithm to compute the page/profile strength, and then list the followers to be notified. FB provides no API to send notifications.